# Workbook level Office AddIn for Excel

Tags: office-js, office-addins

The modern Office AddIns seem to be loaded Application-Wide in their respective applications (Excel, Word, Powerpoint, etc...). I am developing a solution in Excel.

How can I make the CustomTab with the AddIn Commands that I have created in my manifest file ONLY appear in certain workbooks? I am trying to "simulate" a Workbook-Level (as opposed to Application-Wide) addin by having the CustomTab dissappear if it's not relevant for the particular workbook.

*In VBA-based solutions you can manually add the xml metadata for the ribbon commands to each indvidual workbook and thus your commands are implicitly bound to a specidic workbook. I can see that the approach taken by the new/modern Office Addins (the manifest file applied globally to the application) is somewhat at odds with the VBA workbook approach and am looking for any potential workarounds.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no way to do that with the Office Web Add-in model. But it is an interesting suggestion. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). There are some related suggestions already made there. If one fits your needs, just vote it up.